# Stringhandling, cut out part of string

Tags: java, string

I have a string with values like -7.000, 10.000, 0.000, -212.000

Now i want to take away the .000 from the string and also the - in the front if there is one. My values always have to be positive.

So from this examples i has to give me 7, 10, 0, 212 back. How can i do that?

I could do  StringHandling.LEFT(myvalue,1).equals("-")?StringHandling.LEFT(myvalue,2):StringHandling.LEFT(myvalue,1) but then i have the Problem that when my values is 10.000 it just gonna give me 1

Comment: Get data between the hyphen and the period maybe? Of course, you will need to handle the case where either hyphen or period are not present.

Comment: Are you talking about processing that String through Talend Stringhandling routine ? Cause it's a different story then ...

Comment: What is this `StringHandling`?

Answer (score 4):

Why don't you just  parse the string as a number, then apply an 'absolute' operator?

```
String foo = "-50.000";
double bar = Double.parseDouble(foo);
int result = (int) abs(bar);
String yourResult = String.valueOf(result);
```

EDIT after OP comment:

To escape negative numbers, you can precede this code by a little:

```
   foo.replaceAll("-", "");
```

If you just want '378.890' to become '378' there's even simpler:

```
   String foo = "378.890";
   String[] bar = foo.split(".");
   String result = bar[0];
```

And if you need '0378.890' to become '378':

```
   String foo = "378.890";
   String[] bar= foo.split(".");
   String foobar = bar[0]; 
   int result = Integer.parseInt(foobar);
   result = abs(result); // If necessary (depends if you want to handle it at the string level or not)
   String finalResult = String.valueOf(result);
```

Comment: His String may contain numbers like `356.7800` as he mentioned that most of the numbers in the String are `367.0000`,***BUT NOT ALL***!

Comment: Is the goal to truncate these and display '356' or is it to display '356.7800' in this case, and numbers with no precision if they are integers?

Comment: Please wait for OP's comment to get further clarification! Add this comment on the question...

Comment: Sorry for a bad Explanation before. Everything that Comes behind . doesnt mather for me. 356.7800 or 356.7800 has to be 356. I also forgot to mention that i want to turn this value to a integer. So if its -345.401 or 101.00 it has to give me a int of 345 and 101

Answer (score 1):

Use a simple `String.substring()` call:

```
String s = "-50.000";
String out = s.substring(s.charAt(0) == '-' ? 1 : 0, s.indexOf('.'));
```

If the input `s` starts with a minus sign `-`, it will be cut off, and also cuts off at the decimal point so there will be no trailing zeros.

This is the most efficient because it does only what is necessary for the required output. No unnecessary conversions and object creations.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `replaceAll()` or `replaceFirst()` and [regex](http://regexone.com/) like the one below:

```
\.[0-9]+
```

**Example:**

```
String test = "-700.999";
test = test.replaceFirst("-", "").replaceFirst("\\.[0-9]+", "");
System.out.println(test);
```

**Output:**

```
700
```

You can test this and other examples [here](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html).

**Explanation:**

`replaceFirst("-", "")` will delete first occurance of `-` with (as the replacement is empty value).
`replaceFirst("\\.[0-9]+", "")` will delete first occurance of `dot` followed by any number of digits. If there is a possibility that the number can be `700.` and you want to remove the `.` as well, then you can replace `+` to `*` in this regex. `*` means `0` or more occurances while `+` means `1` ore more.

**Further info**

You can also shorten this solution that it will require one `replaceAll()` invokation with a little more complicated regex.

Answer (score 0):

Try with regEx :

```
String yuStr =  "-7.000, 10.000, 0.000, -212.000";
System.out.println(yuStr.replaceAll("-|(\\d+)\\.\\d+", "$1"));
```

Output :

```
7, 10, 0, 212
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion is not a matter of strings but more of numbers. Parsing it as a double and then dealing with its absolute value would take you where you want:

```
Math.abs(Double.valueOf(val).intValue())
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
char[] splitChars = {',',' '};
string samplestring = "-7.000, 10.000, 0.000, -212.000 ";
string[] array = (samplestring.Split(splitChars, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));
char[] splitChars1 = {'.','0'};
for(int i =0; i < array.Length; i++)
{
    array[i] = array[i].TrimStart('-').Replace(".000", "");
}
```

Or if its sure that you will always get .000, in the last then easiear way can be :

```
        char[] splitChars = {',',' '};
        string samplestring = "-7.000, 10.000, 0.000, -212.000 ";
        string output = samplestring.Replace("-", "");
        output = output.Replace(".000", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with simple maths:

```
String foo = "-1.99"; // example
double original = Double.parseDouble(foo);
double parsed = Math.floor(Math.abs(original)); // remove '-' if there is one, then round down
```